# Memory is not released by JTable in Java Swing (String is heavily used)

Tags: java, string, swing

Input hex file can contain atleast half a million lines of data. Hence, GUI should display all of them.

Current Implementation:

1. Creation of JTable.
2. Creation of model by extending DefaultTableModel class in Swing. e.g HexModel
3. String array creation of length 0x10000 e.g. String[] dataString = new String[0x10000] 
   Because each address record in Intel hex file can have maximum 0x10000 data records.
4. Prefill this String array with GAP string e.g. * . We also need to display GAPs of hex file in GUI.
5. Store byte array of data from hex file model (created by parsing input hex file) into String array dataString by iterating through all the data records of current address record.
6. Create String array e.g. rowString of length 0x12 to store String format of address, data part and ASCII string for the data part.
7. Iterate through data records of length 0xFFFF i.e. 0x10000 - 1 and store the following into rowString array.
   a. Store address into first index.
   b. Store data from dataString array of length 0x10.
   c. Store ASCII string. (ASCII string is created by getting ASCII value for each data byte, append them into StringBuilder and convert it into String)
   Finally, add rowString array into HexModel.
8. Once iteration is completed for all address records and its respective data records, HexModel is updated into JTable.

Please note that there is no performance issue while launching GUI. It takes 2 to 3 seconds only for hex file with half million records(10MB file).

But Memory consumption is a BIG ISSUE. For 10MB hex file, memory takes 250MB. 
Main issue is that Memory is not reduced though i closed loaded file from tabbed pane in GUI.

I know that String is heavily used. But what could be best approach to handle this usecase ?

Request your inputs on this memory issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Only load the relevant rows at a time, possibly using a cache. A Memory Mapped file may be useful here - but only create the strings/rows "on demand". Some metadata about the rows might be useful for seeking, etc (depend on data / usages): this metadata should be small in comparison to the full data and probably pre-loaded/computed. The JTable supports paging just fine.

Comment: Based on your provided Information pagination must be a good approach to load as much rows as needed in one page at a time. However, nowadays 250MB of memory consumption is not am issue at all since any PC or laptop has at least 2GB or 4GB of ram.

Comment: The problem about not releasing the memory is based on your implementation since the garbage collection mechanism only can release dead references. Maybe you defined a very wide scope variable for the `JTable` and its model.